# How can I direct users to different pages once they've logged in?

Tags: php, html, authentication, redirect

I have an online portfolio, where I would like different clients to see different versions of my home page once they have logged in using the credentials I have provided.

So for example:

- AcmeInc logs in > sees > acmeinc.html
- BobsBurgers logs in > sees > bobsburgers.html

There won't be many concurrent users (say, never more than 10) I would manually set up each user with a unique id, username, and password. I also have an entry for 'version' where I thought I could assign each user a value, e.g. 1,2,3 depending on the version of the home page I want them to see - although I am of course unsure if this is a viable approach, or there is something easier / better!

I have set up a login system using an online PHP tutorial (I don't know much about PHP), and have a mySQL database correctly linked together and it is working as expected when inputting the user credentials into the login form.

The index.html to my site is a login screen, with a form linking to an 'authenticate.php' file (again from this tutorial - code at the bottom of this post)

On successful login, the user is redirected to home.php, which also has a snippet of PHP at the top to check session status - again attached below.

Any help would be much appreciated - thank you!

**Authenticate.php**

```
session_start();
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'john'
$DATABASE_PASS = 'password';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'users';

$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
        exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
    exit('Please fill both the username and password fields!');
}

if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
        $stmt->fetch();

        if ($_POST['password'] === $password) {
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            header('Location: home.php');
        } else {
            echo 'Incorrect username and/or password!';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect username and/or password!';
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

**Home.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
  header('Location: index.html');
    exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
//html follows//
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all add function `ob_start()` before `session_start()`, see more about `ob_start()` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.ob-start.php) from php manual.

And as @Luka Shield said, you have already this in your code.

### Answer 2

if you want redirect user from `Authenticate.php`, just add this code in your `Authenticate.php` file after line `$_SESSION['id'] = $id;`

```
header('location: user' . $_SESSION['id'] . '.html');
```

Example & Explanation: if user id is 1 after successful login, will redirect to `user1.html` and so etc...

**But are you sure that this solution is logical for your project?**

I think it only makes sense to fetch user information on one page based on the identifier (user-id). Better than creating 10 HTML files, ex. (User1.htm, User2-HTML. etc..). The solution that I will suggest will help you in the future by editing all pages from one place.

Lock at this url
`example.com/user.php?id=1`.

Now I can get the `id` value by get-request, read [here](https://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.get.php) more about $_GET.

So, first of all let's create user page, create new Page `user.php` and paste the following code

I will give you a page example

ex: user.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
      header('Location: index.html');
        exit;
    }

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
    {
        $id = $_GET['id']; // user id that's coming from url example.com/user.php?id=x
            */

        if ($id > 0 && !empty($id))
        {
            /*
                Now the variable $id represents the value of the number coming from? example.com/user.php?id=x

                Depending on this variable, you can implement your idea, or fetch data depending on the id coming from the link
            */
        }


    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks - and do you know how I can then redirect the user to a different version of the home page? e.g. user 1 sees user1.html, user 2 sees user2.html and so on.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, look at my answer. I will add your request in 'Answere 2'.

Comment: Thank you again, very helpful! 

For the code you've provided in Answer 2, if I understand correctly this seems to rely on each user having a page of their own, e.g. 
user 1 >sees> user1.php
user 2 >sees> user2.php, 
user 3 >sees> user3.php

Is it possible to show say user1.php to users 1 AND 3, but show user2.php to user 2?

Answer (score 0):

You have already got this in your code. `header('Location: home.php');` this will then direct users to home.php once they successfully login.

Then on home.php you can add

```
session_start();
// If the user is not logged in redirect to the login page...
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit();
}
```

this will see if user is logged in and if not, redirect user back to login page

[Good login page link](https://codeshack.io/secure-login-system-php-mysql/)  Not sure if this is what you have been using as code is very similar

Comment: Thank you - yes this is the code I've been using. Do you know how I can then show different users a different home page once logged in?

Comment: Im guessing you mean for users and Admins, If i was doing it, i would make 2 versions of home page, one for main users and then one under Admin folder do the login page to redirect to if admins login